# PHPでもっと見る機能の実装

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

今現在、SQLのnewsというテーブルに7,8つデータが入っています。
サイト上の表示ではlimit5で5つまでを表示しているのですが、もっと読むというボタンをつけて、6以降のデータも表示したいと思っています。

いろいろ調べてみるとajaxを使うなどがあったのですが、このページにjqueryを加えるだけで出来ないものでしょうか？

```
  <dl class="clearfix">
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM news";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM news LIMIT 5";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($results as $row) {
                    echo'<dt class="news-date">'.$row["create_date"].'</dt>';
                    echo '<dd class="news-description"><a href="news.php?news_id=' . $row["news_id"] . '">' .mb_substr($row["news_title"],0,10)."...". '</a>';
                    echo "<hr>";
                    } 
                    $pdo = null;
                    ?> 
                    <p id="loading" style="display:none;">loading...</p>
                    <input type="button" id="more" value="もっと読む">
                </dl>



<script>
$(function(){
    $("#more").click(function(){
        $("#loading").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jqueryのload使った実装です。
load自体はajaxで取ってきた内容を要素内に追加するのではなく、既存の中身は削除して置き換えを行います。
ですので、最後に空のdl要素を追加して(38)、そこ(`.clearfix:last`、これは表示されてる内容に対して)にdl要素の子要素(`.clearfix>*`、これはloadで取ってきた内容に対して)を展開するようにしています(46)。
なお`"&time="+$.now()`のくだりはキャッシュ対策です。キャッシュが問題なければなくても構いません。
loadを使うにあたり、php側でページング機能は実装しておく必要があります(11-14)。javascript側との連系も必要です(29,39)。
その他、エラー処理関係(24,33-34,45)や、最終の処理(35-36)あたりもざっくり付けてありますが、適宜チューンしてください。
また、最初の所(1-8)はテストデータの準備です。気にしないでください。

未実装部分としては
- データ出力の際は適切なエスケープ処理を行ってください。
- 途中で増減した場合はズレます。更新頻度が低いなら許容しても良いかと思います。

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("sqlite::memory:");
$pdo->exec("CREATE TABLE news (news_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, news_title TEXT, create_date TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO news (news_title) VALUES (?)");
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $i) {
    $stmt->execute(array("The $i article!"));
}
?><head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script></head><body>
<dl class="clearfix">
<?php
    $page = (int) $_GET["page"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM news LIMIT 5 OFFSET ?";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($page * 5));
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($results as $row) {
                echo'<dt class="news-date">'.$row["create_date"].'</dt>';
                echo '<dd class="news-description"><a href="news.php?news_id=' . $row["news_id"] . '">' .mb_substr($row["news_title"],0,10)."...". '</a>';
                echo "<hr>";
                } 
                $pdo = null;
                ?> 
            </dl>
                <p id="loading" style="display:none;">loading...</p>
                <p id="error" style="display:none;">!!! error !!!</p>
                <input type="button" id="more" value="もっと読む">

<script>
page = <?php echo $page ?>;
$(function(){
    function load_cb(response, status, xhr) {
        $("#loading").hide();
        if (status == "error") {
            $("#error").show();
        } else if ($(".clearfix:last dt").length < 5) {
            $("#more").prop("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $(".clearfix:last").after('<dl class="clearfix">');
            page = page + 1;
        }
    }
    load_cb(null, null, null);
    $("#more").click(function(){
        $("#loading").show();
        $("#error").hide();
        $(".clearfix:last").load("list.php?page="+page+"&time="+$.now()+" .clearfix>*", load_cb);
    });
});
</script></body>
```

Answer (score 2):

SQLでリミットをかけずに全て読み込み、javascriptでその値を読み込めばいいのではないでしょうか？
jQueryのみで実装するのであればjavascriptでその値を持っておく必要があると思います。
また、初期表示はPHPで出力すれば良いかと思いますが、
下記のような感じで、もっと読む押下時にjQueryで動的に追加すれば良いかと思います。

```
<dl class="clearfix">
    <div id="data">
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM news";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $counter=0;
    $defLoad=5;
    foreach($results as $row) {
        if($counter < $defLoad){
            echo'<dt class="news-date">'.$row["create_date"].'</dt>';
            echo '<dd class="news-description"><a href="news.php?news_id=' . $row["news_id"] . '">' .mb_substr($row["news_title"],0,10)."...". '</a>';
            echo "<hr>";
        }else{break;}
        $counter++;
    }
    $pdo = null;
?> 
    </div>
    <p id="loading" style="display:none;">loading...</p>
    <input type="button" id="more" value="もっと読む">
</dl>

<script>
    var loadData = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($results); ?>");
    var defLoad = <?php echo $defLoad; ?>;
    var loadPage = 0;
    $(function(){
        $("#more").click(function(){
            loadPage++;
            for(var n=(defLoad*loadPage);n<(defLoad*(loadPage+1));n++){
                var rowData = loadData[n];
                $("#data").append(
                    $("<dt>").addClass("news-date").append(rowData["create_date"])
                ).append(
                    $("<dd>").addClass("news-description").append(
                        $("<a>").attr("href","news.php?news_id="+rowData["news_id"]).html(rowData["news_title"].substr(0,10)+"...")
                    )
                ).append($("<hr />"));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: var loadData = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($results); ?>");
という行がconsoleエラーになっていて、 
missing ) after argument list
と表示されてしまいました。

特に記述に間違っているようには見えないのですが、何か問題がある感じなのでしょうか？

Comment: 文字列が正常にくくられていないエラーです。出力されたJSONにダブルクォーテーションがあったようですね。出力結果が分からないので調整してくださいとしか言えませんが、シングルクォーテーションに変更して試してください。また、javascript側で配列の上限のチェックをしていません。そのまま使うのであれば調整してください

Answer (score 1):

的外れな回答かもしれませんが、

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news LIMIT 5";
```

を

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news LIMIT ".5*$count;
```

とし、
もっと読むボタン押下時に$countをインクリメントすれば
LIMIT 5, LIMIT 10, LIMIT 15・・・　と増やせるのかもしれません。